# Defining The Inverse Of The Zeta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta

I've recently been searching around the web for an inverse of the zeta function, $ \zeta^{-1}(s) $, somewhat unsuccessfully. I then came across
$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{\eta(s)}{1-2^{1-s}}, $$ where $$\eta(s) = \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{-1^{k-1}}{k^s}$$ I then manipulated it like so:

$$\begin{align*}
\zeta(s) &= \frac{\eta(s)}{1-2^{1-s}} \\[0.1in]
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} &= \frac{1-2^{1-s}}{\eta(s)} \\[0.1in]
\frac{\eta(s)}{\zeta(s)}  &= 1-2^{1-s} \\[0.1in]
\frac{\eta(s)}{\zeta(s)} - 1  &= -2^{1-s} \\[0.1in]
 -\frac{\eta(s)}{\zeta(s)} - 1  &= 2^{1-s} \\[0.1in]
 \log_2\Bigl(-\frac{\eta(s)}{\zeta(s)} - 1\Bigr) &= 1-s \\[0.1in]
-\log_2\Bigl(-\frac{\eta(s)}{\zeta(s)} - 1\Bigr) -1 &= s
\end{align*}$$

So there you go? An inverse of the zeta function. However, when I input it into Wolfram Alpha, it doesn't work, as in:

$$ \zeta^{-1}(2) \approx -1.58496-4.53236i $$
$$ \zeta(-1.58496 + -4.53236i) = 0.282432... -
0.377775... i $$

Any help?

Comment: One could attempt Lagrange Inversion Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You made an arithmetic mistake in multiplying both sides by $-1$:

$$\frac{\eta(s)}{\zeta(s)} - 1  = -2^{1-s} \implies -\frac{\eta(s)}{\zeta(s)} + 1  = 2^{1-s} $$

(By the way, you haven't really produced an inverse of the Riemann zeta function, since your formula depends on the value of $s$ itself, in order to plug into $\eta$.)

Comment: Surely then I could rewrite it as

Comment: $$ \eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) $$

Comment: @OllyBritton: That still depends on $s$.

Comment: But surely to evaluate $\zeta^{-1}(s)$ all you need to do is plug it into the formula and you can calculate the values of $\zeta(s)$ yourself?

Comment: @OllyBritton: Plug **what** into the formula? Remember, the whole point of the inverse of a function is that I can tell you a number, $x$, and you can tell me which number $s$ has the property that $\zeta(s)=x$.

Comment: Note that using $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ also makes your formula a complete tautology, because the $\zeta(s)$ cancels and has no impact on anything:
$$-\log_2\Bigl(-\frac{(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s)} + 1\Bigr) -1 = s$$
$$-\log_2\bigl(-(1-2^{1-s}) + 1\bigr) -1 = s$$
$$-\log_2(2^{1-s}) -1 = s$$
$$-(1-s)-1=s$$
$$s=s$$
Your formula takes in a value of $\zeta(s)$ and then never uses it for anything.

Comment: Also, maybe the point I should have started with is that the Riemann zeta function is not injective, and therefore does not have an inverse everywhere. For example, there are many known values of $s$ for which $\zeta(s)=0$, so there is no way to define $\zeta^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles. We can find an inverse for the zeta function in the the interval $(1,\infty)$ right?